# UILabel Subclass appears as UILabel in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, uilabel, subclass

I'm a experienced C++ programmer trying to create my first Objective-C subclass of UILabel with an added read-only property

```
// UINumericlabel.h
@interface UINumericLabel : UILabel

// Returns true if the numeric display contains a decimal point
@property (readonly,nonatomic) BOOL hasDecimalPoint;
@end
```

---

```
//  UINumericLabel.m

#import "UINumericLabel.h"

@implementation UINumericLabel
// Returns true if the numeric display contains a decimal point
- (BOOL) hasDecimalPoint;
{
   return [self.text rangeOfString:(@".")].location != NSNotFound;
}
@end
```

When I try to reference the hasDecimalPoint property for an instantiated UINumericLabel I get an abort with error

`2012-02-20 18:25:56.289 Calculator[10380:207] -[UILabel hasDecimalPoint]: unrecognized` selector sent to instance 0x684c5c0

In the debugger it shows my  declaration of a UINumericLabel property as being a UILabel *
Do I need to override the (id)init for UILabel in my UINumericLabel subclass?  How do I do that?

```
#import "UINumericLabel.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINumericLabel *display0;
@end
```

When I hover over display0P in the debugger it says it is a UILabel * not a UINumericLabel *

UINumericLabel * display0P = self.display0;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Interface Builder select the label and then open the Identity Inspector.  In the text field "Class" it probably says `UILabel`.  Change that to be your new subclass, `UINumericLabel`.

Comment: Merely declaring the property to be of type `UINumericLabel` is not enough.  You need to tell Interface Builder to use your subclass.

Comment: ipmcc - are you adding more information to my answer or saying that it is not correct.  Just trying to get some clarification.

Comment: Adding information, but re-reading it I can understand the confusion.  What I'm getting at is that the Nib loading code looks only at the xib/nib file when it creates that object graph. It knows nothing of the @property called `display0` and therefore, having that be of type `UINumericLabel` isn't enough.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - but that is what I was telling him to do.

Comment: So it seems my confusion was my thinking that the display0 property was creating the _display0 member object but if I'm understanding correctly it was simply being pointed to the UILabel object created by the Interface Builder.  And even though I was using a UINumericLabel pointer, the run-time identified it as what it really was, namely a UILabel and that's why the debugger showed my UINumericLabel display0P pointer as a UILabel.  Have I got it?

Comment: On further thought, I have another question.  Why was I allowed to assign an object who's type is a parent superclass (UILabel) to it's more specific subclass.  Why didn't I get a compile time error or at least a run-time error when the UILabel object created by Interface Builder was assigned to UINumericLabel * _display0 and also when I assigned property self.display0 to UINumericLabel * display0P?  Is there no protection in Obj-C from doing an invalid downcast assignment like in C++?

Comment: Still waiting on answer my followup question as to why I was allowed to do an invalid downcast without getting an error.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your responses.  As far as a property automatically creating an iVar with _ prepended - I'm not sure if properties do that or not.  About the casting issue - I really don't know - but I'm assuming its because IBOutlet means nothing.  It is just a hint to XCode and IB that this property should be made available to attach a UI object to.  Then when the app runs and the xib is unpacked and everything is wired up and that's when it would instantiate the UILabel and assign it to your UINumericLabel object.  I'll continue this.

Comment: I believe it is possible for an method to return an object of a different type than what is stated.  Go to XCode and make an NSString and init it to an array.  I don't think you'll get an error back when you compile.  Why, I don't exactly know.  I wish I had more information for you.  If you find out more, please comment back.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Brian above, but would add two things: (1) no need for a declared property unless you plan to cache the BOOL value.  Just use a method with a predeclaration in .h, and (2) no need for a subclass in this case.  A better approach would be an extension, like: UILabel+JonN.h...

```
@interface UILabel (JonN)

-(BOOL)hasDecimal;

@end
```

Then, in UILabel+JonN.m...

```
@implementation UILabel (JonN)

// your method as written

@end
```

This is prettier, I think, and solves the problem you were having with IB (which I think @Brian correctly addressed).

Comment: This was only one of several properties I was adding to turn UILabel into a numeric display. I simplified my example for brevity in posting. If I understand your example above this would have to be called with message syntax [self.display0 hasDecimal] instead of dot notation self.display0.hasDecimal.  It was my intent create a new kind of UILabel called a UINumericLabel which had several readonly computed properties.  Without providing an instance variable or an @synthesize it is my understanding that the BOOL value is not cached but computed by the getter on each call.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the property will let you use the dot, and the method will not.  The property creates an ivar: it's just a shorthand for the ivar, getter and setter (and dot notation as syntactic sugar), so I you'll be wasting a little space to make your source code look a little sweeter.  Especially since you're not caching the computation, I think the category method approach is superior in this case ... it's not really a new kind of UILabel.  But your subclass will work (just remember to set the class in IB whenever you paint one).